# How to fix leaking basement window in foundation

Tags: windows, foundation

I am trying to fix leaks in a basement window.  After running water to determine the spot it is leaking, it appears to be leaking between the metal frame and the foundation.

The concrete is chipping under the metal framing.  I went to Lowe's and they said to 1) break away the chipping concrete, 2) clean it well with alcohol, 3) put on a concrete bonding adhesive, 4) put on Quickrete Hydraulic Water Stop cement, 5) spray on a liquid rubber sealant coating called Flex Seal.

I chipped it as far down as it would easily, but it doesn't seem to be far enough to add more cement.  I suppose I could a little bit, but I worry it will not create a good seal against the metal framing. Ideas?

[image: Window with chipping cement below window]

[image: A closer look]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All basement windows will leak given that you have standing water in the area.  This issue is about the drainage of water on this section of your house and not about the shape of the concrete.

Probably the easiest thing to do is to dig out around this area, add some rock and a drain pipe going out.  I can't see in the picture a "well" or cover either.

If this is not "standing water" for sure and you are getting direct rain, then silicone caulk will be far more effective than more concrete.

Comment: It is not standing water and I solved this with silicone caulk and the flex spray that was suggested to me by the Lowes associate.